# Material-UI Grid in React Unique ID for each element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a grid in react which will render.

```
function MouseOver(event) {
 //make btn appear
}

function MouseOut(event) {
 //make btn dissappear
}
return (
    <Grid
      item
      onMouseOver={MouseOver}
      onMouseOut={MouseOut}
    >
      <button className="btn" style={{display: "none"}}>Button</button>
    </Grid>
   );
```

This will create a grid in react. Now I have two functions onMouseOver and onMouseOut. I want this to be mouse events to target each element of the grid individually. If an element in the grid has mouse over it the button's display will become visible only for that element in the grid. I am having trouble targeting that button as I am unable to uniquely identify each element in the grid.

Comment: Your code snippet only has one Grid item and button. It's not clear how your component tree looks like. Generally speaking, you can call your event handlers with argument(s), set component state and have your buttons react to that. `onMouseOut` and `onMouseLeave` (and their respective counterparts) also behave differently in regards to bubbling, which may or may not matter in your case.

Comment: i took out most code because of company code, but imagine there is a grid of say 9 by 9 containers. now i want to make button visible when i hover one of them.